# Rendering joined array to display Rails Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Having a bit of an issue rending rails errors. The main issue is that on the view the errors  display an array output and not joined together (user friendly).  I can add the "join" method in the view and that will work fine on attributes with multi errors.  Although naturally if the attribute only contains 1 error this will break.

So I'm currently attempting to have the errors join in the controller so that if there multi errors on an attribute it will look pretty.  Trying to add the .join method in the view is not working because on the instances where there is 1 error it will break (since you can't invoke the join method on a string)

any help how to make this work in the controller would be great.   Any suggestions on another way of handling this issue is also great.   (from my logic of trying to prettyify/join the array errors in the controller like this)

Controller:

```
if @person.errors.blank? && @person.save
  flash[:info] = "Your profile has been successfully updated."
  redirect_to profile_url(@person) and return
else
  if @person.errors.on(:first_name).is_a?(Array)
    @person.errors.on(:first_name).join
  end
  flash[:warning] = "Sorry, there was a problem saving your profile. Please try again."
  render :edit
end
```

View:

```
%li
        = label(:person, :first_name, "First Name")
        = f.text_field :first_name
        - if @person.errors[:first_name].present?
          %span{:style => "color: red; margin-left: 180px;"}=   @person.errors[:first_name]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use the `to_a` method. It convert string in array and it do nothing for array.

You should create a custom validator like here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations.

After that, you could refactor your code like this

```
if @person.save
  flash[:info] = "Your profile has been successfully updated."
  redirect_to profile_url(@person)
else
  @person.errors[:first_name] = @person.errors.on(:first_name).to_a.join
  flash[:warning] = "Sorry, there was a problem saving your profile. Please try again."
  render :edit
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.  I ended up having to make the adjustment in the view because apparently trying to pass these conditions in the controller was something rails wasn't liking. Not certain if it's something with Rails 2.3.

Answer (score 1):

Stack em!

```
if @person.errors.present?
  @person.errors.each do |err|
    = err
```

Or read this previous post with a very colorful way to go about customizing errors :

[Rails validation error messages: Displaying only one error message per field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569401/rails-validation-error-messages-displaying-only-one-error-message-per-field)