# Duplicate flash error messages with multiple validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am currently validating my model using this code:

```
validates :price, :presence => true, :numericality => {:greater_than => 0}
```

This works fine, except that when I do not enter any value in this field, I get 2 errors - both "Price can't be blank" and "Price is not a number".

I can understand why this happens - clearly it is failing both tests. But i'm wondering if there is a way to ge the validation to stop after one test, since there is no point testing if the number is > 0 if there is no number at all?

Thanks!

Edit: For clarity, I don't want to allow the field to be blank, I just don't want the numericality test to run if it is blank, to avoid 2 error messages for what is really 1 error.

Comment: You may also look into this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569401/rails-validation-error-messages-displaying-only-one-error-message-per-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it will work, but you can try:

```
validates :price, :presence => true, :numericality => {:greater_than => 0, :allow_blank => true }
```

Comment: Sorry, might not have been clear in the question - I don't want to allow the field to be blank, I just don't want the numericality test to run if it is blank, to avoid 2 error messages for what is really 1 error.

Comment: if I remember correctly, the presence validator ignores the allow_blank hash field, so all validators will allow blank values, but the presence one will not, thus yielding just one error ;) I cannot test it here, but think it should work :)

Comment: Just tested this, and it still gives both errors if the field is blank :-(

Comment: Oops, spoke too soon - looks like this actually is working, and it was my testing that was at fault. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you made an edit that is making it work - I thought I had just mistyped. Thanks for your help!