# Custom email validator with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, devise, email-validation

I followed the [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Use-a-custom-email-validator-with-Devise) to add a custom email validator with devise. It works but the errors are printed twice once for each validation like below. How to fix this?
[image: Error message!]

**Update**:
The answer [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4207916/463758) in the comment does not work. It probably works only if all validations are done in one validates call. In my case one validation is done by devise and other is added by me. To be clear, the model looks like below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  attr_accessible :email, :name

  before_save do |user|
    user.email = email.downcase
  end

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :email, email: true, presence: true, reduce: true # This causes 'Email is Invalid' to be printed twice
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails validation error messages: Displaying only one error message per field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569401/rails-validation-error-messages-displaying-only-one-error-message-per-field)

Answer (score 5):

If you just need to change the regular expression that devise is using for email validation, you can do it in `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
config.email_regexp = /\A[^@]+@[^@]+\z/
```

Then you won't need to add additional validation to the email field.

Comment: answer is obsolete use
1. ```Devise.email_regexp``` or
2. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Use-a-custom-email-validator-with-Devise

Answer (score 1):

You can use email validation with Devise email_regexp, just change in `config/initializers/devise.rb`

FROM (because it validates some incorrect emails as valid, like `emn178@gmail..com`):

```
 config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/
```

TO:

```
 config.email_regexp = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

I found this solution [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3820).